# why doesn't my character comparison work?

Tags: java, android, char, ascii

Here is the code where I create the headingString:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.myapp.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String headingString=prefs.getString("directions", getResources().getString(R.string.heading_default));
if (headingString.length()==0) {
   headingString=getResources().getString(R.string.heading_default);
}
```

Here is my problematic java code:

```
Log.i("HeadingActivity", "headingString.charAt(0)==" +headingString.charAt(0));

if (headingString.charAt(0)=='§') {
Log.i("HeadingActivity", "success!");
// other code
}
```

My log only says:

```
I/HeadingActivity﹕ headingString.charAt(0)==§
```

The control doesn't enter into the `if` block even though the characters match.

Why is this not working as intended?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. try printing the integer value of both characters in a `public static void main(String[] args)` method.

Comment: yeah for me also, it goes inside if loop.

Comment: Thanks, I never thought that this could be a problem, as it worked just fine when I used similar code before. I printed this out: (int) headingString.charAt(0) which is 167 and then I took my § sign from the if clause and logged this: (int) '§'. It printed the number 65533 out. Is it possible that i have used 2 different versions of the § sign? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error, I took the headingString from my strings.xml, which uses utf-8. The method charAt(index) returns an integer for the ASCII value. As the ASCII and utf-8 values are not the same value my if clause didn't woork.

Comment: You'd better check the description of [charAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and strings in general in Java. You don't find any valid mention of ASCII. (Also applies to C#, JavaScript, …)